# Some use me frequently - others never at all. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> My beginning lights up your world.
>   My end is pretty logical.
>   My middle is kind of sleepy.
>   Some use me frequently - others never at all.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you a

> Razor

My beginning lights up your world.

> Ra is a sun god

My end is pretty logical.

> OR is a logical operator

My middle is kind of sleepy.

> "Z" usually represents sleeping

Some use me frequently - others never at all.

> Some people shave, others prefer to grow their hair out

Comment: Well answered - everything spot on!

Comment: I think also *raz* is pronounced *rays* which matches the description.

Answer (score 2):

What am I?

> An idling laptop running on battery power

My beginning lights up your world.

> If you boot it up, the screen illuminates a dark room

My end if pretty logical.

> Once the battery is drained, obviously it shuts down, there is no other possibility

My middle is kind of sleepy.

> Since it's idling, it will go into power saving mode

Some use me frequently - others never at all.

> Some people use laptops daily, some don't (have access)

Comment: +1 creativity, but not correct unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer

> sunblock

My beginning lights up your world.

> sun

My end if pretty logical.

> block - like a block of code

My middle is kind of sleepy.

> This I don't know

Some use me frequently - others never at all.

> Some people use sunblock frequently, and others never use it

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, unfortunately, it is incorrect. Your first explanation is on the right track for the correct answer though.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry but I saw this on HNQ and my inner inappropriate side had an immediate alternate answer.

Are you a

> Person who solicits and accepts payment for sex acts (prostitute).

My beginning lights up your world.

> Wink wink

My end is pretty logical.

> Wink wink

My middle is kind of sleepy.

> Well if you're under-performing this would make sense.

Some use me frequently - others never at all.

> Also true